# How to assign different categories to pages in wordpress?

Tags: categories

I am beginner in wordpress, I want to assign my categories that contain multiple posts to particulate page.

So please, anybody guide me?

Comment: what you mean by assign ? do you want to display them ?

Comment: I wont to display them in the page.

Comment: all posts with respective categories ?

Comment: I Wont to display all post that I assign to the particulate page. for exp., if my page name service and my category name food than all food category post display on page Service.

Comment: look at my answer. Modify according to your needs.

Comment: @Lucky You should never ever use `query_posts` as recommended in the accepted answer. It is a really bad function to use which should, in my opinion, be removed from core. Sorry to those whos site will break. It is time to remove useless crap from core

Answer (score -2):

You can create a page template (for service page) and then set it to particular page, on which you want to display posts.

After that open page template and paste below code where you wan to show posts.

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=1'); // cat=1 , id of category you want to show (e.g. cat id of food category )
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // loop for posts with category id = 1 
the_content(); // print content of all founded posts
endwhile; // end loop.
?>
```

#### [Refer this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more help

Comment: Recommending the use of `query_posts` for secondary loops is really bad idea. Use [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

Comment: question doesnt specifies about this, why negative ?

Comment: `query_posts` is a really bad function to use as it breaks the main query, rerun queries, is slow and totally stuffs up pagination and the globals like `$post` and `$wp_query`. It fact, `query_posts` breaks a lot of functionality. Never ever use it.